# Mudar orientação de preenchimento em gráfico

Tags: r, ggplot2

Gostaria de saber se existe a possibilidade de mudar a orientação do preenchimento das cores do seguinte gráfico

[image: Imgur]

O que eu quero é que as cores sejam preenchidas de fora pra dentro. Alguém tem alguma ideia?

```
dat <- structure(list(
    Category = structure(1:15,
      .Label = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4", "ID5", "ID6", "ID7", "ID8", "ID9", "ID10", 
             "ID11", "ID12", "ID13", "ID14", "ID15"), class = "factor"),
    Percentage = c(0.8, 0.32, 0.15, 0.6, 0.4, 0.5, 0.3, 0.7, 1, 0.8, 0.3, 0.9, 0, 0.2, 0.46)),
  .Names = c("Category", "Percentage"), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")

ggplot(data = dat) +
  geom_col(aes(x = Category, fill = Category, y = Percentage), width = 1) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1, color = "darkgrey", size = 1) + #ponto de partida
  geom_segment(aes(x = 1.5, xend = 4.5, y = .75, yend = .75), color = "darkgrey", size = 1) +#2017
  geom_segment(aes(x = 5.5, xend = 15.5, y = .75, yend = .75), color = "darkgrey", size = 1) +#2017
  geom_segment(aes(x = 1.5, xend = 15.5, y = .5, yend = .5), color = "darkgrey", size = 1) +#2018
  geom_segment(aes(x = .5, xend = 4.5, y = .25, yend = .25), color = "darkgrey", size = 1) +#2019
  geom_segment(aes(x = 5.5, xend = 15.5, y = .25, yend = .25), color = "darkgrey", size = 1) +#2019
  geom_vline(xintercept = seq(.5, 15.5, by = 1), color = "darkgrey", size = 1) +
  coord_polar() +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none",
        panel.grid = element_blank())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consegui a resposta no [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48832987/change-fill-colors-orientation). Só é preciso adicionar o comando `scale_y_reverse ()`.

Comment: Eu estava tentando resolver este problema de uma forma completamente diferente. Entendi que o trecho "as cores sejam preenchidas de fora pra dentro" significava que cada setor circular deveria ser preenchido num degradê de laranja até rosa. Tipo, todos os setores circulares seriam laranja para `Percentage` 0,1; verde para `Percentage` 0,3 e assim por diante, até rosa para `Percentage` 1. Eu estava completamente errado (e não, não consegui fazer o gráfico que estou descrevendo).

Comment: Eu fiquei um bom tempo pensando na melhor forma de descrever meu problema, e acabei decidindo pelo que escrevi. Talvez esse seu gráfico possa ser feito com várias colunas de `Percentage` com valores específicos para cada setor. Aí depois teria um `geom_col` para cada um desses, com a opção `fill = cor`, começando pelo mais de fora.